# How does a tcp clients understands the server status codes

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, file-not-found

I am writing a socket programming in C to transfer files from Server to Client. where client sends a filename to server and the server reply with the file content. I couldn't understand how a server can intimate the client when the file asked by the client is not found in server side. Do i have to use any standard to reply a package to client, where the client can understand that as a FileNotFound ?

Comment: Maybe you should read up about the concept of [Communication protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol), e.g. messages, handshake, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your communication model, you are missing a layer of meta-data or control messages. at the minimum, you need to pass a status code before you return the file. I suggest that you implement a simplified version of HTTP client. you can find an example at:

[GitHub - reagent/http: Simple HTTP client in C](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiDmMnSvZLgAhUOCewKHcU8AlUQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Freagent%2Fhttp&usg=AOvVaw2Z6VmZGbsm5kvMpPY4DrSt)

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, I added a layer for meta-data and it worked fine.